# Getting assemblyinfo of a feature in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have a method that collects the assemblyversion of a webpart. (works fine) :

```
 private void GetVersion(object control, out string name, out string version)
    {
        name= control.GetType().ToString();
        version = control.GetType().Assembly.GetName().Version;
    }
```

Now I want to achieve the same for my features:

```
 private void GetFeatureVersion(SPFeature feature, out string name, out string version)
    {
        name = feature.Definition.GetTitle(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-us"));
        version = feature.GetType().Assembly.GetName().Version;
    }
```

But in the Assembly of feature.GetType() isn't the information of my feature, but of sharepoint (14.0.0.0). The name var is fine but thats no surprise as it is not read out of the type.

Comment: A feature can have no assembly at all, so why do you use `feature.GetType().Assembly`? Isn't [SPFeatureDefinition.Version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spfeaturedefinition.version.aspx) what you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the following to the template.xml - File.

```
ReceiverAssembly="$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$"
```

That did the trick

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the version of the feature receiver assembly you can do the following:

```
string version = Assembly.Load(feature.Definition.ReceiverAssembly).GetName().Version;
```